# Stop listening to express route

Tags: node.js, express

I'm building an asset handling framework for express.

It will auto-reload files that are changed, without restarting the entire application.  It knows what files made what bindings(like `app.get('/asdf')`), and when that file is changed, it will unbind the route, and rebind with the changed file.

lets say you have an express router file like this:

```
app.get('/my_route', method);
```

once you change it, I need to run something like ~~~~~

```
 // pseudo code -- I need something like this
 app.unbind('get', '/my_route', method);
```

~~~~~

before I reload it.  So is there an `unbind` method?

Will I need to manually edit the routes object?

Once I find out, I will be able to change a router file, and have it unbind the old listeners, and re add the new ones.   I've done something [similar for socket.io](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19016912/how-do-i-dynamically-update-socket-io-callbacks-without-restarting-the-server), but I need to find a way to unbind in express

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can loop through [`app.routes`](http://expressjs.com/api.html#app.routes) and remove the route, or directly change the callback. This is what the routes object might look like:

```
{ get: 
   [ { path: '/',
       method: 'get',
       callbacks: [Object],
       keys: [],
       regexp: /^\/\/?$/i },
   { path: '/user/:id',
       method: 'get',
       callbacks: [Object],
       keys: [{ name: 'id', optional: false }],
       regexp: /^\/user\/(?:([^\/]+?))\/?$/i } ]
```

So you could create something like this:

```
function unbind(method, path) {
  var routes = app.routes[method];
  for (var i = 0; i < routes.length; i++)
    if (routes[i].path == path)
      routes.splice(i, 1);
};
```

The original route handler would be in `app.routes.method[i].callbacks`, which returns an array.

Answer (score 2):

I'm assuming that the route path itself doesn't change.

In the end, what changes is the "method" that is attached to said route, so if you could abstract away the method definition and allow it to be changed by "reloading" a file that was modified, then you would not really need to "unbind" the route.

Maybe an intermediate function ?

Just my $0.02

Cheers

Comment: Intermediate function would be my suggestion too.

Comment: I'll give a +1 because I thought about this,  but I'd like the framework to be flexible so they don't need to learn a special syntax for defining routes to fit into an abstraction layer.